# Handle different URL patterns in Zuul filters

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, gateway, netflix-zuul

I have two types of URL patterns as below.

1. /gateway/secure/api/user/getUser
2. /gateway/nonsecure/api/user/getUser

(Context root of zuul gateway application is `gateway`)

Using zuul filters I'm trying to implement two different logics based on `secure` and `nonsecure` URL patterns. I've written a pre-filter and seems it's not even executing that filter for above URL patterns. I could see gateway is throwing `404`. When I try to access microservice without `secure` or `nonsecure` its working as expected. Below are the property changes I've done so far.

Context root of downstream microservice is api/user

```
zuul.prefix=/secure
zuul.routes.user.path=/api/user/**
zuul.routes.user.service-id=user

zuul.prefix=/nonsecure
zuul.routes.user.path=/api/user/**
zuul.routes.user.service-id=user
```

I've already tried by giving `zuul.prefix` and it seems prefix is setting as globally and cant apply only for specific routes. How can I achieve this? Can anyone please advice.Thanks

Comment: There's nothing global that will allow you to do this. You'll need to do it for each route.

Comment: @spencergibb thanks for the advice. I've added prefix as above for each route and seems its taking only last prefix. Any idea? Am I missing any thing?

Comment: There can only be one zuul.prefix

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the `zuul.prefix` property affects all mappings and can only be defined once. So, drop the `zuul.prefix` property and add the corresponding prefix to each `zuul.routes.*.path` properties:

```
zuul.routes.user.path=/secure/api/user/**
zuul.routes.user.service-id=user

zuul.routes.user.path=/nonsecure/api/user/**
zuul.routes.user.service-id=user
```

---

Note that, according to the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy):

> `zuul.stripPrefix` only applies to the prefix set in `zuul.prefix`. It does not have any effect on prefixes defined within a given route’s `path`.

Comment: I was able to handle this using different approach, with the help of web server.  Anyway thanks for the answer @Nicolau :)